# Cannot obtain credentials for computer account - client not found in kerberos database

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, ubuntu-20.04

I have successfully joined an ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) to an Active Directory.
Therefore, I can log in with AD-Accounts, obtain and renew the ticket grantin ticket for the user, and access network shares with Kerberos authentication.

However, I struggle to obtain the initial credentials for the computer account:

```
admin@comp01:~$ sudo KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab
[sudo] password for admin:
[232252] 1645435537.855061: Getting initial credentials for host/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN
[232252] 1645435537.855062: Looked up etypes in keytab: rc4-hmac, aes128-cts, aes256-cts
[232252] 1645435537.855064: Sending unauthenticated request
[232252] 1645435537.855065: Sending request (187 bytes) to COMPANY.LAN
[232252] 1645435537.855066: Sending initial UDP request to dgram 172.27.17.6:88
[232252] 1645435537.855067: Received answer (84 bytes) from dgram 172.27.17.6:88
[232252] 1645435537.855068: Response was from master KDC
[232252] 1645435537.855069: Received error from KDC: -1765328378/Client not found in Kerberos database
kinit: Client 'host/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials
```

I have spent several hours on that issue without progress. Probably I am missing some essential steps.
The requested principal is contained in the local keytab on the ubuntu machine:

```
root@comp01:~$ klist -kte
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 COMP01$@COMPANY.LAN (arcfour-hmac)
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 COMP01$@COMPANY.LAN (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 COMP01$@COMPANY.LAN (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 host/COMP01@COMPANY.LAN (arcfour-hmac)
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 host/COMP01@COMPANY.LAN (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 host/COMP01@COMPANY.LAN (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 host/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN (arcfour-hmac)
   4 02/17/2022 07:34:59 host/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:35:00 host/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:35:00 RestrictedKrbHost/COMP01@COMPANY.LAN (arcfour-hmac)
   4 02/17/2022 07:35:00 RestrictedKrbHost/COMP01@COMPANY.LAN (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:35:00 RestrictedKrbHost/COMP01@COMPANY.LAN (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:35:00 RestrictedKrbHost/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN (arcfour-hmac)
   4 02/17/2022 07:35:00 RestrictedKrbHost/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 02/17/2022 07:35:00 RestrictedKrbHost/comp01.company.lan@COMPANY.LAN (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

And the principal is also registered on the AD-Domain controller:

```
> setspn -L comp01
Registrierte Dienstprinzipalnamen (SPN) für CN=COMP01,CN=Computers,DC=company,DC=lan:
            RestrictedKrbHost/comp01.company.lan
            host/comp01.company.lan
            RestrictedKrbHost/COMP01
            host/COMP01
```

The ubuntu machine has been joined to the AD-Domain using

```
> realm join company.lan
```

And the Kerberos configuration file is as follows:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = COMPANY.LAN
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true
[realms]
        COMPANY.LAN = {
                kdc = DC.company.lan
                admin_server = DC.company.lan
                default_domain = company.lan
        }
[domain_realm]
        .company.lan = COMPANY.LAN
        company.lan = COMPANY.LAN
```

Forward and reverse DNS are also looking good:

```
> nslookup comp01
Server:  DC.company.lan
Address:  172.27.17.41

Name:    comp01.company.lan
Address:  172.27.17.131

> nslookup 172.27.17.131
Server:  DC.company.lan
Address:  172.27.17.41

Name:    comp01.company.lan
Address:  172.27.17.131
```

I am really thankful for any hint that guides me in the right direction.

Comment: The syntax that works for me translated to your network (use the sAMAccountName of the computer object, at the FQDN of the domain: " kinit -k COMP01$@COMPANY.LAN

Comment: @Semicolon I have tried the following (I suppose the position of the dollar sign was intentionally right after the computer name?): `kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab COMP01$@COMPANY.LAN` `kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab COMP01@COMPANY.LAN` and `kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab COMP01.$@COMPANY.LAN` All attempts end up with the following result: `kinit: Keytab contains no suitable keys for COMP01@COMPANY.LAN while getting initial credentials` Only the principal names are different: COMP01@COMPANY.LAN, COMP01COMPANY@COMPANY.LAN and COMP01.COMPANY.LAN@COMPANY.LAN

Comment: How did you obtain this keytab? Note that dollar is a special character in POSIX shells, so you'll have to escape it. A better way to check if a principal exists in the database is with the `kvno` tool.

Comment: @Semicolon You were totally right, but I was too blind to see the solution. Pitfall: I needed to place tick marks around the identifier; otherwise, the $ gets replaced with "COMPANY.LAN", leading to the odd credentials in my previous comment. I only realized the problem after the answer from @user1686 . Therefore, the successful command to obtain the ticket is `kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab 'COMP01$@COMPANY.LAN'` Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Active Directory-flavoured Kerberos there is a distinction between "user" (client) and "service" (target) principal names. Specifically, **only** the account's sAMAccountName can act as the client principal, its SPNs cannot.

The account name of computer objects is always the hostname in upper case and suffixed with a `$`, e.g.  for a computer named "COMP01" the account name would be `COMP01$`.

Meanwhile `host/comp01` and `host/comp01.company.lan` only exist as *service* principals – an AD KDC will issue tickets for clients requesting "host/comp01" as the target server, but doesn't allow them to act as clients during initial authentication. They exist in your keytab only to be used on the "acceptor" side.

Comment: Indeed, that has solved my problem! In combination with the comment from @Semicolon I was able to obtain a ticket using `kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab 'COMP01$@COMPANY.LAN'` (Dollar suffix and tick marks are very important!) Thank you very much for your help!